# SQLite in Android: is there a way to use a limited number of rows in my application, or should I remove them by hand?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am currently building a database recording events on the phone, but as I don't want to make this a huge database, 100 events are more than enough.

This will keep my database light en efficient.

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to limit the number of rows other than

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE _id <= "+limitId;
```

and I could run this code when the user launch/leaver the app, but I am expecting a better way to achieve this

Is there a more convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by limiting in deletion you always delete only rows which satisfies condition there could be limiting factor while you select but not in delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `ContentProvider`, you can implement your DELETE in `onInsert`, deleting a single row on every insert of a single row:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE _id IN (SELECT min(_id) FROM myTable)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean limit to the 100 newest events ?
if so, there is no better way to do it as you did: checking for entries on every insert and delete old entries if necessary.

It's just a matter of taste how or where you do your check, as flx mentioned you could do it in the ContentProvider or as you probably did in the BroadcastReceiver or Service where you actually add the new row. You could also set up a Trigger on your table, but the main idea remains the same. Here a link if you're interested in triggers:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_triggers.htm